# How to make everything under the navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar fixed to the top. When scrolling, almost everything goes *under* the navbar, but there is this piece of text that goes above the navbar. 
Can I force the navbar to be at the topmost, or force the text to be bottom-most?

Note: to observe the issue, please add arbitrary content so you will be able to scroll through the page.

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/q8prw19c/1/

```css
  .caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}
.caption span.border {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 10px;}
.parallax { 
    background-image: url("http://www.firsthdwallpapers.com/uploads/2014/03/hd-wallpapers-wide-pack-41-20.jpg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.topnav {
 position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
 </div>
 <div class="parallax">
  <div class="caption">
      <span class="border">test</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave the body a z-index of 1 and your #topnav element a z-index of 2, that way it will be on top of everything you add to your site.

```css
html, body { 
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 }

body {
  z-index: 1;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  
}

.caption span.border {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  
}

.aboutMe{
  z-index:2;
}

.parallax { 
    background-image: url("http://www.firsthdwallpapers.com/uploads/2014/03/hd-wallpapers-wide-pack-41-20.jpg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.topnav {
 position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;

  z-index:2;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<html>

</html><body>
 
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="parallax">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border">test</span>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="aboutMe">test</div>
 
 <pre>
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 </pre>
 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a "z-index" css prop to the absolutely positioned element.

Comment: To be more precise add `z-index` to `.topnav` element

Answer (score 0):

Give `.topnav` a higher z-index.

Answer (score -1):

See the Update :

```css
html, body { 
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
 }

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  
}

.caption span.border {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 18px;
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  
}

.aboutMe{
  z-index:2;
}

.parallax { 
    background-image: url("http://www.firsthdwallpapers.com/uploads/2014/03/hd-wallpapers-wide-pack-41-20.jpg");
    height: 100%; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.topnav {
 position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;

  z-index:99;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<html>

</html><body>
 
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
 </div>
 
 <div class="parallax">
  <div class="caption">
    <span class="border">test</span>
  </div>

 </div>
 
 <div class="aboutMe">test</div>
 
 <pre>
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 </pre>
 </body>

</html>
```